# Arbitrary's Meaning

Tags: terminology

I am not a native English speaker nor have I studied Physics in English before. I came across this word "Arbitrary" when I read a Mathematics for Physics book. I don't understand what it means. Here is the sentence "where $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary scalars."

Comment: It means that you can choose any scalars $A,B\in\mathbb R$ without any restrictions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Arbitrary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arbitrary?s=t) means "undetermined; not assigned a specific value."  For example, the statement $x+x=2x$ is true for arbitrary values of $x\in\mathbb R$, but the statement $x+x=2$ is *not* true for arbitrary values of $x$ (only for a *specific* value: $x=1$).

Comment: Think of *arbitrary* as meaning the same as *any.*  So you get "where $A$ and $B$ are any scalars."